# Service Unavailable Server currently undergoing maintenance. Webmaster: please contact support. Error 503

Tags: wordpress, plugins, web-crawler, shared-hosting, http-status-code-503

I've been using Hostgator hosting for a while but suddenly Hostgator started to close some website with " Service Unavailable" and It's because CPU resources is high, so Hostgator provide me some steps to optmize my wordpress  ( Updating my wordpress , reviewing my pluggins, also I Limit WebCrawlers and Bots with robot.txt, google and bing and I have a Super Cache and wp-optimize ). Well After that I told Hostgator to review them to take out the restriction they put  them back up after 2 or 3 days Its very frustration I don't know what It could be .? any help will be appreciate it.

Also I just notice in my google console there are some errors and I trying to delete but I can't find it.

Thank you in Advance

[google console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/720D2.png)

Answer (score 0):

how much visitors do you have per month? And did you look in your account on hostGator, there is a point that show the ressource usage. Look at it.

A good solution could it be, to install a caching plugin, like w3 Total Cache Plugin or WP Super Cache Plugin. That should help a lot by saving resources.

The point in your image is a list of elements that couldn´t be delivered. The server had to much to do with other stuff, so he wasn´t able to complete the requests, as result you see the 503 Error code.